# Find and join two lines using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I want to join next line when Colon is matches in first line using regex I tried all regex replace but no luck Can anyone help me please here is code what I tried. Pr

```
function copy() {
  var txt = $('#result1').val().replace(/prefix_ago/g, ' : <br />');
  txt = txt.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '');

  $('#id1').html(txt.trim());
}
```

there is unique word in my conversation that is prefix_ago which I am replacing to Colon and

```
<textarea class="result" id="result1" rows="10" cols="150" style="font-size:11px;resize: none; width:225px;">
User 1 prefix_ago 
Hi How are you 
User 2 prefix_ago
I am good How about you 
 </textarea> 
<button onClick="copy()" > Copy & Replace</button>
<div id="id1">

</div>
```

Comment: Regex or Daniel can you help me please @regex101.com, Daniel Beck

Comment: Daniel can you help me please @Daniel Beck

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. Could you please re-word it?

Comment: (1) You're confusing jQuery with JavaScript. You may use jQuery to read information to the DOM and to write it back, but everything in between is JavaScript. Of course, jQuery *is* nothing more than a JavaScript library, but it's important to know that text manipulation with regular expressions has nothing to do with jQuery. (2) You haven't described the problem clearly. Can you be more specific about the exact problem, with more examples of the input and output?

Comment: @MichaelGeary I have found solution for that using regex in jquery. I will post answer here

Comment: jQuery doesn't have anything to do with regular expressions. It will help you a lot if you understand the difference between JavaScript, the language (which includes regular expressions) vs. jQuery (a library of functions written in JavaScript, mostly for DOM manipulation).

Comment: Sorry, this is unclear. What should the final result look like? [This is what you are doing](https://regex101.com/r/FQOyM2/1) now. Do you want to get [this kind of output](https://regex101.com/r/FQOyM2/2)?

Comment: If you do not clarify what you need to get in the end (in the console? in the rendered HTML view?) we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function copy() {

var regex = /^(.*?prefix_ago)/gm;
var subst = '\#$1';
var originaltxt = $('#result1').val().replace(regex, subst);
originaltxt = originaltxt.replace(/(#)/gm, '<br>');
$('#id1').html(originaltxt.trim());
}




<textarea class="result" id="result1" rows="10" cols="150">
        User 1 prefix_ago 
        Hi How are you 
        User 2 prefix_ago
        I am good How about you 
         </textarea> 

        <button onClick="copy()" > Copy & Replace</button>
        <div id="id1">

</div>
```

I have inserted # tag when regex matches prefix_ago, this is will bring all into single lines and then I have break lines using same # tag and then I removed # tag.