# How to insert # tag in each line using regex

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I am trying to insert # tag to each line using regex but its just replacing entire line can anyone help me please

here is code what I tried

```
function copy() {

var regex = /^(.*)/gm;
var subst = '\#\1';
var originaltxt = $('#result1').val().replace(regex, subst);
$('#id1').html(originaltxt .trim());

}

<textarea class="result" id="result1" rows="10" cols="150" style="font-size:11px;resize: none; width:225px;">
User 1 prefix_ago 
Hi How are you 
User 2 prefix_ago
I am good How about you 
 </textarea> 
<button onClick="copy()" > Copy & Replace</button>
<div id="id1">

</div>
```

Comment: Come on, why `\1` in JS? You need to use the `$1` notation in JS regex replacement strings. Using regex101 *after* checking [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). I think the *`subst`* should be `'#$1<br/>'`

Comment: yes that's right thank you @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Please consider accepting/upvoting my answer below if it works/you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `#$1<br/>` replacement.  JS regex uses `$n` notation for backreferences, and `<br/>` will insert line breaks in the HTML view.

```js
function copy() {

var regex = /^(.*)/gm;
var subst = '#$1<br/>';
var originaltxt = $('#result1').val().replace(regex, subst);
$('#id1').html(originaltxt.trim());

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="result" id="result1" rows="10" cols="150" style="font-size:11px;resize: none; width:225px;">
User 1 prefix_ago 
Hi How are you 
User 2 prefix_ago
I am good How about you 
 </textarea> 
<button onClick="copy()" > Copy & Replace</button>
<div id="id1">

</div>
```

Comment: Can you help me on this query please [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511165/find-and-join-two-lines-using-jquery) @WiktorStribiżew